# How to get redirected url in C# WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webbrowser-control

I have a webpage that loads, does some calculations and then does a JavaScript redirect to another webpage. It looks something like this:

**http://www.mysite.com/startpage.html**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.location = "http://www.mynewurl.com";
});
</head>
<body>
Something
</body>
</html>
```

Now I have an asp.net MVC app that loads a WebBrowser control and my **goal** is to be able to retrieve `http://www.mynewurl.com` from within my C# WebBrowser control.

My WebBrowser code looks like:

```
WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser
                                    {
                                        ScrollBarsEnabled = false,
                                        Size = new Size(Width, Height),
                                        ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true
                                    };

    webBrowser.NewWindow += WebBrowserNewWindow;
    webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.mysite.com/startpage.html");


    //wait for it to load
    while (webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }

    Uri myUrl = webBrowser.Url;  //This is how I have been trying to get it.
```

So when I load my webBrowser control I send it to `http://www.mysite.com/startpage.html`. It does a javascript redirect to `http://www.mynewurl.com`.  I want to somehow capture that url in my c# code.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: I noticted that I can use 
    Thread.Sleep(10000); 
right after the while loop loads and it actually gets my values. I guess the browser takes forever to accept a response from the javaScript.  Obviously this isn't an acceptable time to wait. Looking for another solution.

Comment: I have decided not to pursue this. I'm not sure how to close this post.

Answer (score 0):

HttpWebRequest.Referer perhaps?  Or maybe append whatever data you need as a query string.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to answer this post - even it's almost 2 years since it was posted - as it is listed in the top results in search engines (e.g. google), but without providing me with a solution...

After some searching I've found a solution to this question, which can be found here:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/115195/webbrowser-newwindow-event-does-not-give-the-url-of-the-new-window-in-eventargs#details

This solves the problem of getting the URL of the new window, when the Cancel property of CancelEventArgs is set to TRUE.

With hope that this might help other people, with this problem, as it has not been resolved in the .NET platform ...

Comment: That url is returning a 404 from the microsoft wesbsite.